# IA32 Assembly - How do you create two random numbers between 1 and 10?

Tags: assembly, random, x86, integer

I'm relatively new to IA32 Assembly, and I'm trying to code some simple programs with it. One of which involves creating two random numbers between 1 and 10. I've done some research on this. One option is using `RdRand` for random number generation, but I can't see if there is anyway of setting parameters for 1 and 10.

I did also read some information about using the system clock in order to get a number, but I don't know how reliable that would be.

Many thanks!

Comment: Do `rdrand`, divide the result by 10, take the remainder, add one.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you! Would this be the same if you were doing different numbers? Say, 1 to 25, would you divide by 25?

Comment: Yes, same principle applies.